# Excel VBA : How to write code for this in vba which return the address

Tags: excel, vba

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(B:B,MATCH(C23,A:A,0)))
```

I have tried this but It does not work.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.cell("address", Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet1.Range(("b3"), Range("b2").End(xlDown)) _
, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(c23, Sheet1.Range(("A3"), Range("a2").End(xlDown)), 0)))
```

There is no cell for the worksheetfunction but It is there in the cell function in excel function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this one (you can wrap it in a function if needed):

```
Dim ind
Dim rng As Range

With Sheet1 
   ind = Application.Match(.Range("c23"), .Range("A:A"),0)
   If Not IsError(ind) Then
      Set rng = Application.Index(.Range("B:B"), ind)
      MsgBox rng.Address
   Else 
      MsgBox "There is no match"
   End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
Dim add As String
add = Sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Range("C23"), _
Sheet1.Range(("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)), 0) - 1).Address
```

simoco's solution will be better as it checks for errors, but I felt it was still worth sharing